# What could possibly make Dojo.destroy() doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have two lines of code like this:

```
var parent = dojo.query(this).parents("div").first();
dojo.destroy(parent);
```

By firebugs, I can clearly see the var `parent` is [div#row-2.form-record]
But dojo.destroy(parent) seems not working(the div is still visible) and push the view to the top of the page and firebugs quit debugging mode.

So what's going on?

Comment: what's the dojo version ? 
dojo.destroy is deprecated, you should use dojo/dom-construct::destroy() instead 
(Source: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/destroy.html)

Comment: first returns a nodelist and destroy accepts a node or id.

Comment: @David McMullin how can I get the node instead of nodeList? I am using dojo 1.6

Comment: it acts like an array, you can just grab the first element using `[0]`.